# Uncaught TypeError: and blinking of cursor in textbox not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am making a html form where I will choose items from list box then a input text box will be generated automatically where I will put quantity for selected item if I choose one item twice it will alert that the box for this item already generated, for that purpose I am making my createElement variable value to none, everything working as I want but it's throwing an error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

... on this line:

```
blueDiv.appendChild(createInput);
```

... and blinking of cursor in text fields is not appearing, Is this normal while my things are working as I want?

```
function createFunc() {            
    var getElem = document.getElementById("itemsList");
    var optValue = getElem.options[getElem.selectedIndex].value;
    var blueDiv = document.getElementById("blueDiv");
    var createInput = document.createElement("input");
        createInput.type = "text";
        createInput.name = optValue;    
        createInput.id = optValue;

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");       

    for(var x=0; x < inputs.length; x++){  
    var inputsName = inputs[x].getAttribute("name");
        if(optValue == inputsName){
            alert("Textbox for this field already exists");
            createInput = "a";
            }              
    }
        blueDiv.appendChild(createInput);            

    }

    <html>
    <form id="theForm" action="" type="post">  

    <select id="itemsList" name="select_pro" class="formTxtInputmany"   
    onchange="createFunc()" >

        <option>SELECT PRODUCT</option>
        <option value="21">KEY CHAIN</option>
        <option value="22">BISCUITS</option>
        <option value="23">COOKING OIL</option>             
        </select> </form>
        <button class="SubmtBtn" onclick="makeJson()">click</button>
        </html>
```

Comment: The error message doesn't mention the exact line?

Comment: ya it says the line 54 which is blueDiv.appendChild(createInput);

Answer (score 0):

The Error says

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

If you look closely you do not have "blueDiv" defined in your markup.

Your code is perfectly fine, just need to have div defined

```
<div id="blueDiv">
```

Edit: Sorry I posted wrong error message but still can you validate, if you blueDiv exists

Comment: i know i didn't show for purpose just to have minimum lines of code, but it's there

Comment: Where did you copy that error message from? That's not the one in the question...

Comment: i copy it from console

Comment: Hmmm Yeah right. I overlooked it. You are right that's not the error but still what I explained is pretty well correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the message says. Here's the relevant code:

```
var createInput = document.createElement("input");
createInput = "a";
blueDiv.appendChild(createInput);
```

You create the `createInput` variable as instance of `Node` but then store a **string** in it.

Comment: yes you are right, Is there any other way where i can do something and not get error and cursor blinking comes back to normal?

Comment: I'm confused about your needs... You have invalid code, code that must have been written to accomplish something. But you don't want to accomplish that something, you just want to make the browser ignore the invalid code?

Comment: ok let me try to explain, I am trying to get Json to pass it to php for further process when i choose 3 items from list and it's create 3 text boxes  which is fine, now if accidently I choose the item i choose before then i do not want to generate another text box for the same item for that I am making the creatInput set to nothing

Comment: Then you have to write into the `.value` property rather than wipe out the entire object.